How could I List all the CommonPrefixes first with listObjectsV2?
I have a lambda function requesting data from S3 using AWS-SDK. It is consumed by a webapp used as a file directory, but when the app request to create a new folder or directory, it doesn't show until the user clicks several times on the next pages using the StartAfter value I send on the response.The bucket has around 24000 files, and I need to send all the folders at the beginning of the request to show'em on the view first (the front end sorts the CommonPrefixes at the begining of the page as directories on the view)
I already list the objects on this way:
module.exports.getDirectory = async (bucketPath = "", StartAfter = null) => {
    await initS3();
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Prefix: bucketPath,
        Delimiter: "/",
        MaxKeys: 300
    };
    try {
        if(StartAfter) params.StartAfter = StartAfter;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
        const data = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
        return {
            content: data.Contents, 
            Prefix: data.Prefix, 
            CommonPrefixes: data.CommonPrefixes, 
            IsTruncated: data.IsTruncated
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {err: err};
    }
}

Do I need to sort the folder when it is created, or is there a way to get all of them when I request the objects the first time the service is consumed?

Sorry, but it is unclear what you are actually asking. Does your code return all of the CommonPrefixes? Are you saying that the a newly-created folder takes a while to be returned in the response? Also, please note that directories do not actually exist in S3 -- you can create objects in non-existent directories and the directories will be magically created (because they don't actually exist). If you do create a directory, it actually just creates a zero-length object with the name of the directory, which forces the directory to appear.

Note that using StartAfter to paginate results when you also specify Delimiter will lead to all sorts of edge cases of missing items depending on exactly how the bucket is laid out as you paginate through the common prefixes but effectively skip over the keys.  You should use NextContinuationToken with ContinuationToken to prevent these artifacts and properly list the common prefixes and keys in the pages.

No, my code doesn't return all the CommonPrefixes, I thought it could always be listed just because it was a different property, but it seems not to be the case, I already tried using ContinuationToken and it's the same case, perhaps I have to communicate the user it's under the limits of the system, I haven´t the option to do that directly on s3 neither, thanks 4 the comments btw
